# Автозаполнение и виртуальная клавиатура

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем добрый день)
У меня проблемы со связкой виртуальной клавиатурой с ajax автоматическим заполнением, я вот сделала лист автозаполнением но он реагирует только на нажатие клавиатуры или на нажатие мышки (onclick, onmousedown) итд, а хотелось бы чтобы он появлялся при вводе букв.
Вот автозаполнение:

```
var xmlHttp  
function showState(str){ 
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
   xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else if (window.ActiveXObject){
   xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
if (xmlHttp==null){
    alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
return
}

var url="auto.jsp";
url += "?txtContent=" +str;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

А это скрипт виртуальной клавиатуры, скажу честно джаваскрипт я понимаю плохо, поэтому нашла готовое и изменила под себя:

```
var jsKeyboard = {
    settings: {
        buttonClass: "button", // default button class
        onclick: "jsKeyboard.write();", // default onclick event for button
        keyClass: "key", // default key class used to define style of text of the button
        text: {
            close: "Закрыть"
        }
    },

    "keyboard": [], // different keyboards can be set to this variable in order to switch between keyboards easily.
    init: function(elem, keyboard) {
        jsKeyboard.keyboard["default"] = jsKeyboard.defaultKeyboard;
        jsKeyboard.keyboardLayout = elem;

        if (keyboard != null && keyboard != undefined)
            jsKeyboard.generateKeyboard(keyboard);
        else
            jsKeyboard.generateKeyboard("default");

        jsKeyboard.addKeyDownEvent();
    },
    focus: function(t) {
        jsKeyboard.currentElement = $(t);
        jsKeyboard.show();
    },
    keyboardLayout: "", // it shows the html element where keyboard is generated
    currentKeyboard: "default", // it shows the which keyboard is used. If it's not set default keyboard is used.
    currentElement: null,
    generateKeyboard: function(keyboard) {
        var bClass = "";
        var kClass = "";
        var onclick = "";
        var text = "";

        var s = "";
        s += "<div id=\"keyboard\">";
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardHeader\">";
        s += "<div onclick=\"jsKeyboard.hide();\"><span>" + jsKeyboard.settings.text.close + "</span><span class=\"closex\"> X</span></div>"
        s += "</div>";

        /*capital letter*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardCapitalLetter\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].capitalLetter, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*small letter */
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardSmallLetter\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].smallLetter, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*number*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardNumber\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].number, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        /*symbols*/
        s += "<div id=\"keyboardSymbols\">";
        $.each(jsKeyboard.keyboard[keyboard].symbols, function(i, key) {
            generate(key);
        });
        s += "</div>";

        function generate(key) {
            bClass = key.buttonClass == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.buttonClass : key.buttonClass;
            kClass = key.keyClass == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.keyClass : key.keyClass;
            onclick = key.onclick == undefined ? jsKeyboard.settings.onclick.replace("()", "(" + key.value + ")") : key.onclick;

            text = (key.isChar != undefined || key.isChar == false) ? key.value : String.fromCharCode(key.value);

            s += "<div class=\"" + bClass + "\" onclick=\"" + onclick + "\"><div class=\"" + kClass + "\">" + text + "</div></div>";

            bClass = ""; kClass = ""; onclick = ""; text = "";
        }

        $("#" + jsKeyboard.keyboardLayout).html(s);
    },
    addKeyDownEvent: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter > div.button, #keyboardSmallLetter > div.button, #keyboardNumber > div.button, #keyboardSymbols > div.button").
            bind('mousedown', (function() { $(this).addClass("buttonDown"); })).
            bind('mouseup', (function() { $(this).removeClass("buttonDown"); })).
            bind('mouseout', (function() { $(this).removeClass("buttonDown"); }));

    },

    changeToSmallLetter: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "none");
        $("#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "block");
    },
    changeToCapitalLetter: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter").css("display", "block");
        $("#keyboardSmallLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "none");
    },
    changeToNumber: function() {
        $("#keyboardNumber").css("display", "block");
        $("#keyboardSymbols,#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "none");
    },
    changeToSymbols: function() {
        $("#keyboardCapitalLetter,#keyboardNumber,#keyboardSmallLetter").css("display", "none");
        $("#keyboardSymbols").css("display", "block");
    },
    write: function(m) {
        var t = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val();
        t += String.fromCharCode(m);
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(t);
    },
    del: function() {
        var t = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val();
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(t.substring(0, t.length - 1));
    },
    enter: function() {
        showState();
        var t = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val();
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(t + "\n");
    },
    writeSpecial: function(m) {
        var t = jsKeyboard.currentElement.val();
        t += m;
        jsKeyboard.currentElement.val(t);
    },
        show: function() {
        $("#keyboard").animate({ "left": "200" }, "slow", function() { });
    },
    hide: function() {
        $("#keyboard").animate({ "left": "-900px" }, "slow", function() { });
    },
    defaultKeyboard: {
        capitalLetter:
            [
                    // 1st row
               { value: 1240, buttonClass: "button button_a" },{ value: 1030 },{ value: 1186 },{ value: 1170 },{ value: 1198 },{ value: 1200 },
               { value: 1178 },{ value: 1256 },{ value: 1210 },
               { value: "Delete", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_enter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", keyClass: "key key_del" },

        // 1st row
               { value: 1049 },{ value: 1062 },{ value: 1059 },{ value: 1050 },{ value: 1045 },{ value: 1053 },
               { value: 1043 },{ value: 1064 },{ value: 1065 },{ value: 1047 },{ value: 1066 },
             //  { value: "del", isChar: "false", onclick: "jsKeyboard.del()", buttonClass: "button button_del", keyClass: "key key_del" },
        // 2nd row
               { value: 1060, buttonClass: "button button_a" },{ value: 1067 },{ value: 1042 },{ value: 1040 },
               { value: 1055 },{ value: 1056 },{ value: 1054 },{ value: 1051 },{ value: 1044 },{ value: 1052 },

// 3rd row
           //    { value: "abc", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_smallletter", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSmallLetter();", keyClass: "key key_smallletter" },
               { value: 1071 },{ value: 1063 },{ value: 1057 },{ value: 1048 },{ value: 1058 },{ value: 1068 },
               { value: 1041 },{ value: 1070 },{ value: 1046 },{ value: 1069 },{ value: 1061 },
        // 4th row
               { value: "123", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_numberleft", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToNumber();", keyClass: "key key_number" },
               { value: 32, buttonClass: "button button_space" },
               { value: "ENG", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_symbolsright", onclick: "jsKeyboard.changeToSymbols();", keyClass: "key key_symbols" }
```

Но вот изменить так чтобы считывалось сразу с нажатий с клавиатуры не удалось, помогите:) А вот так я попыталась включить это в свой jsp

```
<input id="txtContent"  onfocus="jsKeyboard.focus(this); clean(this);" type="text" name="name" onmousedown="showState(this.value);" style="position:relative;right:100px;"></div>
```

Comment: вот у меня вопрос, ваш клавиатурный плагин использует jquery, 

 1. так зачем, почему, с какой целью и из каких соображений вы реализуете ajax через XMLHttpRequest вручную ?
 2. Не надо вешать события в разметке
 3. jsp ? это вроде про java не про js.
----

Comment: 1.Я просто другого способа не знаю, я вообще впервые пробую(
2.Почему?
3.У меня страница то на jsp + servlet, а виртуальная клавиатура на js

Comment: 1. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
2. потому-что тогда приходится держать функции к которым обращаетесь в глобальной области видимости, вам уже должны были рассказать почему это плохо.
3. ну так может отделить js от jsp ? сделайте отдельным файлом.

Comment: эти файлы и так раздельно лежат

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте на ваш input обработчик onkeyup-а аналогичный обработчику onmousedown

Comment: onkeyup я делала, он вроде обработчик нажатия кнопок клавиатуры. Работает с обычной клавиатурой но не с виртуальной

Comment: а. тогда вызывайте showState в конце выполнения generate.

Comment: а как я вызову showState  если он в jsp объявлен, а generate в js отдельно?

Comment: не понимаю. showState и generate - javascript-овые функции, что мешает из одной вызвать другую?

Comment: как вызвать js файле функцию на jsp? 
Если знаете как, покажите пожалуйста, потому что я не знаю:(

Answer (score 0):

Можно заюзать хороший текстовый редактор, вот пример с автозаполнением
https://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html